# Core data error while using nsoperation

Tags: ios, core-data, nsinvocationoperation

I'm using some core-data entities in a method that is concurrent, (it's in a `NSInocationOperation` object)... and I'm getting this error:

```
CoreData: error: NULL _cd_rawData but the object is not being turned into a fault
```

How to avoid this? The method just does some calculation with the core data values, no new entities are added , no entities are deleted and none are modified ...

Comment: If I say [RTFM](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) and then add a smiley face will that make it better? :)

Comment: Well, I'm getting same errors. I've read that many times, but doesn't help much, as I'm using MagicalRecord and always using saveWithBlock static method to provide me with context.